# Access OData services from two different system in SAP Web IDE

Tags: sapui5, hana, sap-web-ide

I have two OData services on two different systems, for which I have added destinations in HCP and entries in *neo-aap.json* file.

```
{
    "path": "/sap/opu/odata",
    "target": {
        "type": "destination",
        "name": "ABC",
        "entryPath": "/sap/opu/odata"
    },
    "description": "ABC"
}, {
    "path": "/sap/opu/odata",
    "target": {
        "type": "destination",
        "name": "XYZ",
        "entryPath": "/sap/opu/odata"
    },
    "description": "XYZ"
}
```

With this, I'm able to access only one system's service i.e. OData service which is on `ABC`. When app loads app tries to load hit metadata for 2nd OData service as well in `ABC` which is obviously not there, hence fails.

How do I access the OData service on `XYZ` system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 'path' is the same, only the first one will be matched. Set different paths for your destinations.
The 'path' property in the neo-app.json is just an alias for your destinations. With your config, this means, whenever in your app, you request something from '/sap/opu/odata/... ' the application will overwrite this part of the path with the URL you configured in the Destination.

Just make something like this:

```
{
  "path": "/ABC/sap/opu/odata",
  "target": {
     "type": "destination",
     "name": "ABC",
     "entryPath": "/sap/opu/odata"
  },
  "description": "ABC"
}, {
  "path": "/XYZ/sap/opu/odata",
  "target": {
     "type": "destination",
     "name": "XYZ",
     "entryPath": "/sap/opu/odata"
  },
  "description": "XYZ"
}
```

And then make sure you use "/ABC/sap/opu/odata" or "/XYZ/sap/opu/odata" whenever you set your model data sources.

Answer (score 1):

This, from my perspective, is a bug.
The key used for locating the destination is the "`path`" value so you will always hit the first destination.
You can resolve this by changing the path from `/sap/opu/odata` to `/sap/opu/odata1`
You then edit your dataSources in your manifest.json: adjust the "`uri`" with the adjusted path on any models you are trying to point to the 2nd path.

I have written on this [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/02/12/connecting-to-multiple-sap-systems-and-environments-dev-qa-prd-from-one-sapui5-application/) and am busy trying to get SAP to change this behaviour.